# Unable to specify different grid columns settings for page and attachment

Tags: 8, views

I am trying to build a views grid display where I have two rows of 3 items each, and then one row of of four items. To me, the logical approach would be to use a primary display in a grid format, and then an attachment, since the layout is slightly different. However, this does not work, because it is impossible to have different grid settings for the primary display and the attachment.

For instance, I set the number of `columns` to 3 for the page display. However, when I create the attachment display, set the `columns` to 4, and attach it to the page display, when I go back to the page display, the columns in the grid settings is set to 4. In order to get 4 items in a row in the attachment without affecting the parent display, I have to use the `unformatted` format and do theming.

Is there a way to have separate grid settings for an attachment vs the parent display? There is no option in the grid settings for overriding for just that display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* apply different `Format` to different Views Displays.

In your Attachment Display you have to click on the **Format** option, *not* on the **Settings** link. This will open the modal dialouge where you change the Format for the Attachment, but before you save make sure you change the **For** option to **This attachment (override)**.

[image: views Attachment Override Format]

The default option for the **For** is "All displays" so if you change it under Attachment, it will automatically change on your Page Display as well, unless you override it like I described above.

Just remember that the overriding option appears on the modal dialogue where you're choosing the option, not on the "Settings" modal that depends on which option is set.